# Not been able to write to a file, after reading from another file using java.nio

Tags: java, nio

I am trying to read one .java file and trying to write it to another file by using the below code.

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JavaToHtml
{
    private Path actualPath;
    private Path targetPath;
    private Path sourcePath;

    private BufferedReader reader;
    private BufferedWriter writer;

    public JavaToHtml(String source, String target)
    {
        sourcePath = Paths.get(source);
        sourcePath = sourcePath.toAbsolutePath();
        actualPath = Paths.get(target);
        targetPath = actualPath.toAbsolutePath();

        Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");

        try
        {   
            reader = Files.newBufferedReader(sourcePath, charset);
            writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(targetPath, charset);

            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                            // This thing is working.
                System.out.println(line);
                            // This thing is not working.
                writer.write(line, 0, line.length());
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new JavaToHtml(args[0], args[1]);
    }
}
```

Now the thing is, in my while loop i am able to read the source file without any issues but the new file (The target) which is created is always empty. Moreover the compiler throws no errors, neither at Compile Time nor at Run Time. Am i doing something wrong ? Please, show me some light, as this being my first question.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to close BufferedWriter and BufferedReader when you don't need them anymore:

```
reader.close();
writer.close();
```

From [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/buffers.html):

> Buffered input streams read data from a memory area known as a buffer;
>   the native input API is called **only when the buffer is empty**.
>   Similarly, buffered output streams write data to a buffer, and the
>   native output API is called **only when the buffer is full**.

With `close()` call you implicitly tell it to flush the buffer and close it...

Comment: You should elaborate a bit more and explain why nothing is written if the buffered stream isn't closed (flushed actually), and insist on the fact that these should both be closed in a finally block.

Comment: @PrimosK : Thankyou, closing both the things sorted things out for me. But can you put some light as to why that happened? Bless You.  Regards

Comment: @JBNizet : May you tell me why that happened, closing both the things sorted things out for me ?  Regards

Comment: learned something from that answer by myself. the offset is applied to the string which should be written :o

Comment: A buffered writer, as its name indicates, buffers the characters written to it in an internal buffer in memory. Once the buffer is full, the buffered writer actually writes the content of the buffer to the file, and then clears the buffer. You may also tell it to write to the file stream by calling flush. flush is automatically called when the writer is closed. So, if you don't flush the buffer, everything stays in memory, and nothing is written to the file.

Comment: Continued: The writer must also be closed to close the underlying file descriptor, which is a limited OS resource, and also to make sure the rest of the code and other processes can open the file without waiting for the JVM to exit. That's why it's very important to close it in a finally block, which is guaranteed to execute even if an exception is thrown. Read the Java IO tutorial. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Comment: @JBNizet : Thankyou for the info. Actually that's what i was reading too. So started doing things. Thankyou for every bit of info. May God bless you. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to just save all the data to a string and then write that string down with writer.write(str). This works only if the data is not to big (otherwise you'll get a out of memory exception).
You should also flush the writer everytime when you add a line, just to make sure everything is there :

```
writer.flush()
```

Comment: The offset argument in the write method is an offset from the start of the given String. It's used to write a substring of the given argument. This line is perfectly OK.

Comment: i just realized that. thanks for the info. actually, two people got their mind cleared ;) edited my answer to not state bullshit.

Answer (score 1):

Do flush(), your writer to print the contents of the file on the file, so that it can free the Buffer from already placed content.

Comment: @GagandeepBali sorry to post here, why isn't your web site working?

Comment: @joeyrohan : Actually, I am hosting that site from my home computer for free. So when I shut down my computer, that site goes down too :-). I keep my computer on for some weeks, but now a days I started shutting it down daily :( Though since my computer is ON now, I guess it's working :-), I might shut it down tomorrow.

Comment: @GagandeepBali just sent u a msg...hope u got it.

Comment: @joeyrohan: I guess you might have to send that message again. Seems like my network was acing some issues lately :(

Comment: @GagandeepBali na..not working..can i have your e-mail or something from somewhere?