# unable to write to file with java

Tags: java, swing, file, io

I have wrote a simple java GUI program to write the content of a text area into a file:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Convert {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyFrame();
    }
}


class MyFrame extends JFrame{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton button = new JButton("Convert");
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(500, 400);
    String fileName = "result.txt";

    MyFrame() {
        super("converter");
        setVisible(true);
        setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        panel.add(button);
        button.setLocation(0, 0);
        button.setSize(this.getBounds().width, 100);

        panel.add(textArea);
        textArea.setEditable(true);
        textArea.setLocation(0, 100);
        textArea.setSize(this.getBounds().width, this.getBounds().height - 100);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                try {
                    File file = new File(fileName);
                    if (!file.exists()) {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }

                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

                    String text = textArea.getText();
                    textArea.setText("");
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);

                    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

                        String line = scanner.nextLine();
                        byte[] utf8 = line.getBytes("UTF-8");
                        line = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");

                        bw.write(line);
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }

                }

                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.print(e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note that the input source is in utf-8 (chinese character) and i am able to print out correctly. However, the result.txt file is empty. Even if i try bw.write("asdf") it's still empty.

Comment: Or you can call `flush()` inside the `while` loop, to `flush` out the contents of the `buffer`, as cited in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8869378/1057230) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing to close the BufferedWriter. Closing it will do the flush and close of the writer and you should see the contents in your file. You need to add the following.

```
bw.close();
```

And here is where you need to put the close():

```
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

                    String line = scanner.nextLine();
                    byte[] utf8 = line.getBytes("UTF-8");
                    line = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");

                    bw.write(line);
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                // close the buffered
                bw.close();
```

**Note:** Ideally putting it in the finally block makes more sense because if there is an exception even then it will get close.

```
  try {
                File file = new File(fileName);
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }

                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

                String text = textArea.getText();
                textArea.setText("");
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);

                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

                    String line = scanner.nextLine();
                    byte[] utf8 = line.getBytes("UTF-8");
                    line = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");

                    bw.write(line);
                    System.out.println(line);
                }

            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.print(e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    bw.close();
               } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.print("Exception while closing the bw");
               }
            }
```

Comment: when? after each write?

Comment: @OMGPOP yes outside the while. If you do it in while, it will close it after the first write and subsequent writes will throw error.

Comment: you put bw.write() in the last line?

Comment: when i put it after each write, i only write the first line. but if i put it outside the while loop, the file is empty again

Comment: turns out to be other problem. it's ok now

Comment: @OMGPOP Are you getting any exception? I have updated my answer with an example of closing it in finally block, try that.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure that you have closed the FileWriter, or in your case, the buffered writer. So all you gotta do is

```
bw.write(line);
System.out.println(line);
bw.close();
```

this will close the open buffer, and allow it to write whatever is in the buffer to the file you are creating.

Hope this helps!